# view file application/views//view..php not found

Tags: php, xml, pdo

```
public static function view($name, array $vars = null){
    if(preg_match('/\\\\/', $name)){
        $view_data = explode('\\', $name);
        if(count($view_data) == 3)
            $file = APP_PATH.DS.'views'.DS.$view_data[0].DS.$view_data[1].DS.'view.'.$view_data[2].'.php';
        else
            $file = APP_PATH.DS.'views'.DS.$view_data[0].DS.'view.'.$view_data[1].'.php';
    }
    else{
        $file = APP_PATH.DS.'views'.DS.'view.'.$name.'.php';
    }
    if(!is_readable($file)){
        throw new Exception('view file application'.DS.'views'.DS.$view_data[0].DS.'view.'.$view_data[1].'.php not found.');
    }
    else{
        if(isset($vars)){
            extract($vars);
        }
        require($file);
    }
}
```

> [21-Apr-2015 13:10:30 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: view_data in /home/realitycards/public_html/test/system/load.class.php on line 28

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: first define $view_data = ''; out side of if and before working on it please check that  $view_data is having some value or not means apply check if(isset($view_data ) && !empty($view_data)){// then all other code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your variable `$view_data` only gets defined in the first `if` statement.  It looks like in the `if` statement below that you are using `$view_data` even though it hasn't been set.

```
if(!is_readable($file)){
    throw new Exception('view file application'.DS.'views'.DS.$view_data[0].DS.'view.'.$view_data[1].'.php not found.');
}
```

You either need to set `$view_data` in your `else` statement, or in the exception above, use the `$file` variable that you've already set:

```
if(!is_readable($file)){
    throw new Exception('view file '. $file .' not found.');
}
```

Comment: @Christian that probably means that your variable $name is 'default/header.php', looking at your concatenation.

Comment: on my local computer works perfect , on centos 6 easyapache works now but had to edit all files from view.name to name